# How to change the current web page innerhtml using php

Tags: php

I am running a local joomla test site and I would like to update the inner html text of  Reading  based on the changing content of a slide data item from a slideshow which is manipulated in php file.

I have coded this javascript within a html block of the php file;

```
     <script>
       var $sel = <?php echo json_encode($item->imgcaption) ?>;
       document.getElementById('category').innerHTML= $sel;
     </script>
```

This code works but not dynamically. I am being given the last stored value of $item array, that is populated by a php 'for' statement that goes through the slideshow array variable and store into the $item array.

so my question is this:

Is there a php code to access/manipulate directly the innerHTML of webpage instead of using Javascript (client-side) that I could insert within the php 'for'?

...at each iteration of my 'for' block going through he slideshow my  content should change.

Comment: Try looking into AJAX.

Comment: PHP runs on the server; JavaScript runs in the browser. As Mike said, you need AJAX to make a request to the server-side script which can be written in PHP and return the value.